# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest

So, I am a beginner into Android and Java.  While I was experimenting with Intent today, I incurred an error.

Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
I searched the whole internet to solve the issue failed.

THE MERGED MANIFEST:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQekr.png)

THANK U SOO MUCH

Comment: "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs" . To help you it would be nice if you include the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that duplication tag in Manifest file and also check the correct integration of file provider.check this link

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manage-manifests